# Create Admin Menu for Post depending on category of post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a new admin menu with all post functionalities available So I am trying to create a new menu with having a post category 'news' and **post-type - post** 
So I have added below function but it still changing naming and functionality of original post menu.

```
function custom_post_type() 
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'News', 'Post Type General Name', 'texdomain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'News', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'texdomain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'News', 'texdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent News', 'texdomain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All News', 'texdomain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View News', 'texdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New News', 'texdomain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'texdomain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit News', 'texdomain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update News', 'texdomain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search News', 'texdomain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'texdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'texdomain' ),
    );

    // Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array
    (
        'label'               => __( 'News', 'texdomain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'News news and reviews', 'texdomain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,

        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor

        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'category'),

        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 

        'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */  
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => false,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'Post', $args );

}

/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not 
* unnecessarily executed. 
*/

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
function custom_post_news_search( $query ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ) {

        //   $strSearchUrl = esc_attr($_GET['post_type']);
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'category_name'    => 'News',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear.. Why are you overwriting the global `$wp_query` object? Are you trying to add an admin menu which when clicked, will load posts from the "News" category only?

Comment: @Sally CJ I have to create admin menu with the same functionality like post-menu which will be only working for particular post category and having post type also post

Comment: `post` is a built-in/internal post type, so you should use a different *slug* - e.g. `new_post` as suggested in the current answer. And I believe that answer has all the necessary information for you to at least move on the proper way.. But you could also create an admin menu which points to `wp-admin/edit.php?news=1` and on that page, filter the `WP_Query` (via `pre_get_posts`) so that the posts list table shows only posts from the "News" category, which means the admin menu would act as a *shortcut* to using the "Categories" drop-down menu on that page to filter the posts... Cheers.

Comment: in the future whenever you ask at so, please format the code like I've adjusted now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Post" is already taken. So you cannot register another post type with this name. So with this out of the way you have three other options.

**Option 1:**

Create a custom post type naming "New Posts"  or new_posts as slug and "News" as  its taxonomy.

**More information:**

- How to register custom post type ( [Codex Site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) )
- How to register custom post type ( [Developer Site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) )
- How to register custom taxonomy ( [Codex Site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) )
- How to register custom taxonomy ( [Developer Site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) )

**Option 2**

If you insist on having post type as post. You can just create a new taxonomy named "News" and attach it to default posts.

**More information:**

- How to register custom taxonomy ( [Codex Site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) )
- How to register custom taxonomy ( [Developer Site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) )

**Option 3**

This one is slightly complex than others.

- Create a New category named "News" for Posts.
- Create an admin page.
- Use WP_List_Table to get the same kind of view as default posts and custom post types.
- Query posts having your "News" category and list them here.
- (Optional) Create edit pages for your target posts in case you do not want to use the default one.

**More information:**

- Administration Menus ( [Codex Site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus) )
- How to create new admin menu page ( [Developer Site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) )
- How to use WP_List_Table ( [Codex Site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) )
- How to use WP_List_Table ( [Developer Site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/) )

Hoping this will be useful. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy to create a new sub-menu under `Posts` to list (or filter) a category under it. Just place the following code in your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu'); 
function my_admin_menu() { 
    add_submenu_page('edit.php', 'News', 'News', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?category_name=news'); 
}
```